# Proof verification regarding countability of a given set.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, proof-verification

[image: Here <span class=]$f(z)$ is a transcendental entire funtion">

Attempt: To prove $E$ is a countable set, I think one needs to show that $E_0$ must be of the form $$E_0 = \mathbb{C} - (\mbox{some countable set})$$.
So that $E = \mathbb{C}- (\mathbb{C}-(\mbox{some countable set})$ implying that $E$ is countable.

Now, the set $\{f'(p): f''(p)= 0\}$ should be countable since if it is uncountable, then $f''(p)\equiv 0$ which implies that  $f'(p)$ is a constant, a contradiction to the fact that $f'(z)$ is univalent.

I am not sure about the second term. Any help to understand it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $E$ is the complement of a countable set in the complex plane $E$ **cannot** be countable.

Comment: Can you please explain how $E_0$ is countable?